# ASP.NET VB Changes in Stocks Prices Prompt

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'd like to ask about the way in ASP.NET VB to detect the changes in stocks prices, if the price inceased, the containing cell inside the grid blinks in green, decreased will blinks in red?

ex: if the price now 10.00$ and increased to 10.01$ the containing cell will blink with 1 second in green..!! Many thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to have a JSON/XML feed that provides the necessary stock symbols, the current trading price, and the time of the last update which is then loaded via AJAX in the background every 'X' seconds.  You would capture the previous price and the new price and compare the two.

jQuery/Javascript provides a lot of transitions to help improve the UI on an app such as you described and also has a pretty easy-to-use implementaton of AJAX, via `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Thanks RobB for your rapid support, actualy I'm using Obout grid and grid refresh method and i'm not sure what best method to capture the previous price, is it to have a hidden column that captures the previous prices and refresh this column in a bit longer interval than the grid refresh interval..!! I assume there is better way..any idea!!

Comment: Sorry i should clear this in the begining. obout grid refresh method will refresh the whole grid, so i would not be able to preserve the previous price.this is the problem i'm facing...thanks.